# ios - UITableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath method is not called If I set it's background color to clearcolor

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have created the custom `UITableViewCell` with `UIImageView` and `UILabel` on it. 
Now when I tap the `UIImageView` or `UILabel`, `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method is called. However if I tap outside of `UIImageView` or `UILabel`, then `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method is not calling.

When I analyse the cause I encounters strange behaviour. In my custom `UITableViewCell`, I set the background color for `UITableViewCell` view and it's `contentView` to `clearColor`.

If I set background color to `UITableViewCell` contentView, then the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` is called. But if I set the color to `clearColor`, then the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method is not called.

Why is this happening?

EDIT: IB Design added.

[image]

Comment: Can you please display your design screenshot?

Comment: @IOSDeveloper added the IB design screenshot.

Comment: disable UserInteraction for both ImageView and Label and Try tap on Cell @SuryaSubenthiran

Comment: @BalajiRamakrishnan already tried. not works.

Comment: Did u set cell selectionStyle anywhere ??

Comment: no. I didn't set selectionStyle anyplace in the code.

Comment: check once in `willSelectRowAtIndexPath` method is clled or not

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik willSelectRowAtIndexPath also not called.

Comment: are you connetcted the delegate of the tableview to fileowner

Comment: delegate, datasource both are connected. didSelectRowAtIndexPath is not called only if I set the background color to clearcolor. If I set background color to other colors, it's called.

Comment: It is not possible. I think you are doing some other mistakes. check twice, because i am using table view with background color as clear color to every elements like tableview, cell ,cell's contentview etc. it directly shows the color of my self.view's background color

Comment: @Lion My table view is inside today extension. I think Issue only happens for the today extension. Just checked for other target, all works fine. Why in today extension issue happens. Added the public repo for the sample project, for reference. https://github.com/surya-subenthiran/TableViewSample.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can export the "cell.subviews" and "cell.contentView.subviews" like this:

```
 NSLog(@"cell.subviews = %@",cell.subviews);
 NSLog(@"cell.contentView.subviews = %@",cell.contentView.subviews);
```

make sure where are your UIImageView and UILabel .
after that ,you can know which view will receive the responds events and resolve it.

By the way ,I hope to see the main code you describe.

hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Debug view hierarchy so you can get better idea.

Click the Debug View Hierarchy button ([image]) in the bar at the top of the debug area to inspect a 3D rendering of the view hierarchy of your paused app.

By this you will get idea about view hierarchy and came to know which view get response first when you select row

Refer this [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode_Overview/ExaminingtheViewHierarchy.html) for more detail.

Hope this will help :)

Comment: My table view is inside today extension. I think Issue only happens for the today extension. Just checked for other target, all works fine. Why in today extension issue happens. Added the public repo for the sample project, for reference. https://github.com/surya-subenthiran/TableViewSample.